# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified with WCF client certificate authentication configured

Tags: wcf, private-key, x509certificate2

I have a pfx (create with openssl) with CSP = "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider".  Certificate's key usage is set to Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement.  Certificate is imported into LocalMachine, in Intermediate Certification Authorities.  The reason for that CSP option is because I want to have the private key stored in the TPM when the certificate is imported into the Windows Certificate Store.

I have a WFC service (.net framework 4.6) with certificate authentication configured.  When the service starts (service is hosted in console app  during dev, and running in elevated privileged as Administrator), it throws

```
System.ArgumentException: It is likely that certificate 'CN=xxxx' may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.
```

Have googled and a number of posts have suggested that it could be a permission to the private key that is the issue.  But I have no idea where is this key located?

Or is there other causes to this error?

Comment: There is a similar issue in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc336754-4b17-418d-86f2-e67a80271843/using-x509certificate2-to-get-privatekey-causes-cryptographicexception-quotinvalid-provider-type?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: The error is the same, however for me, this error is thrown from WCF doing it's thing when certificate authentication is configured, I don't have any of my own code explicitly access the privateKey.

Comment: ok, some more googling on this tells me the .Net Framework version I am on doesn't support CNG/KSP certificates out of the box. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/unsupported-scenarios